# a good companion for C/C++ in the 3D world?

Tags: c++, c, 3d, programming-languages, mathematical-optimization

I'm not really convinced about how C/C++ performs under certain circumstances, especially when it comes to keeping the approach to the math world simple and efficient, I don't know how to explain this since i have skilled my self on only other 2 languages: Python and Java ( and other languages for the www world like html, js, php, etc etc ... ) and they are all really different from C++ because the way they are designed.

What I don't like it's probably a mix between syntax and performances, for example C++ doesn't offer a support for matrices or vectors natively, all boils down to doubles and floats and you need to always keep an eye on what you are presuming you are doing because of the binary arithmetic that sometimes can give you unexpected results, and since your matrix it's not a primitive type it's treated like any other custom class without any particular optimization on the math, even if it's "math" and sometimes it can be optimized.

I will probably repeat myself but since C++ it's the only compiled languages that i know, that is right for some kind of performances, I can't really compare what it's offering to something else, but some aspects of the C++ world are cumbersome and not really shaped in a way that they can fit my needs, it's probably the best language to build an engine and the biggest part of my application, but i would appreciate some suggestions about what language can be the perfect companion in a 3D application and basically, an application with a lot of math.

Comment: So... what's your question? You seem to have a lot of misconceptions about many things. For example, "*C++ doesn't offer a support for matrices or vectors natively, all boils down to doubles and floats and you need to always keep an eye on what you are presuming you are doing because of the binary arithmetic that sometimes can give you unexpected results*" This is no less true of Java or Python. And that "binary arithmetic" is called "what your processor does". Matrices and vectors *are* doubles and floats.

Comment: Java is also a compiled language. — C++ doesn't offer native support for linear algebra, but the few languages that do (FORTRAN, APL, Matlab...) are hardly better for "3D applications" (though it's not entirely clear to me what you mean by that). You can quite easily get high performance for LA in C++ by using libraries such as GSL or Eigen, and otherwise: the math in C++ is really quite fast. — If there is one question, it's whether it's worth to bother with C++' problems like 10-screen-long error messages, that usually come up when you try to implement complicated stuff efficiently in it.

Comment: C++ is used for core computation in lots of 3D game engines and CAD software.  Operator overloading allows you to write natural mathematical expressions with new types like matrices, vectors, intervals, ...  Templates give compile-time polymorphism.  I'd say C++ is one of the best choices for math-heavy applications as long as you're prepared to do manual memory management.

Comment: @NicolBolas i don't care about how my CPU works, this doesn't change my point, for example do you care about endianess when coding in C/C++ ? this is a job for the compiler, not for the coder.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I consider Java more like an interpreted language rather than a compiled one, it doesn't even generates a real executable. About the troubles: dealing with a library based on templates it's not an easy task in C++, especially when it starts throwing errors; it's really strange to me that these days you can't find a real programming language for the math.

Comment: @japreiss can you be more clear about what you mean with this ?

Comment: @user1849534 basically, C++ has some features that actually make it better than the average language for writing numerical code that's both expressive/easy to read and performs well.

Comment: Use a library or write your own matrix and vector types. C++ supports defining your own types so you can write `matrix4x4<float> m = a * b * rotation3d<float>(rx, ry, rz) * 3.5;`. There are techniques (e.g. expression template libraries) to make chained operations (as in the `m` example) as fast as possible. The library also alows you to change the implementation (e.g. SIMD/vectorized operations, inline assembly or unrolled loops). Coupled with tests, this will verify the implementation is correct, reducing bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not convinced about your line of thought.

About the math part: Doing it with native C++ is cumbersome, I believe that. However, there are many libraries available that help you do your maths in a way that is efficient both in development and runtime performance.

For example, have a look at the [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org). Eigen heavily uses templates and compiler optimization to get the most out of your maths. I have yet to find great optimization potential (well, you can always get a bit by using processor specific optimization such as BLAS, but that could be done using Eigen as well).

I'm no expert on the 3D-part, though.

No language offers all features that you might ever need on it's own. That is what libraries are for. You should be able to find a suitable library for most problems you will encounter in C++.

About the syntactic difficulties: I do not know how far you have dug into C++. I learn something new every day - things that used to take me 10 lines of code when I started learning now can be done in one - without loosing performance or readability, on the contrary, usually gaining more clarity of the code. Thus: It is all about experience.

Comment: libraries provide functionality, i need something else, i can easily reach a certain level of functionality/features, the problem is about the internals and how I'm forced to explain myself in the code. For example in the real world a matrix can be a 3x3 set of values, a compact statement, in C++ they are just 9 separated values, with no guarantee about where they will be stored, for example i can easily pay 9 times for 9 values with 9 access in memory when what i need it's a data structure or a primitive type with all the values in a contiguos space.

Comment: Wrong. Maybe you should first learn about the language before judging. Even a simple double array is stored in adjacent memory locations. That certainly holds for vectors and matrices of all libraries I know.    Eigen for example let's you write code that is fairly close to MATLAB-code while still offering very high performance.

Comment: @user1849534: You really need to read up on Data Driven Programming.  The C++ language allows you to order your variables to be most efficient access with the hardware. For example, you can declare a small matrix that fits into the processor's cache and operate on that, then haul in the next matrix.  A little more difficult to do in FORTRAN.  If you really want platform specific efficiency, code it in assembly language.